# Smart banners stopped working

Tags: ios

I noticed smart banners haven't been showing on our webpages for some time to promote our app. Assuming a problem on my end, I tried a few things with no success. It's not the phone because I can see ted.com smart banners. Created a simple page with just the ted smart banner code (test on iOS device):
http://devgm2.walkjogrun.net/utils/ted.html
That works.  Replaced their app ID with mine:
http://devgm2.walkjogrun.net/utils/sb.html
Hm. It's definitely my app ID and we're definitely still in the app store.

Has anyone else seen this problem?

UPDATE: 3/28/13 - still happening on my iPhone 5.

Comment: Both smart banners work fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you previously closed out the smart banner on your page? Because if so it won't show again. This is stored in a cookie. So maybe try clearing out the cookies on your phone for your site and see if it shows.

Comment: Apple told me the same thing finally in response to my radar - the cookies were the issue. It's a shame there isn't anything in the docs to tell you this...

Comment: Is there any way not to store the response in cookie?